# What is a "local no-change full rebuild"?

Tags: makefile, build, gnu-make, android-source

Android's AOSP 10 no longer includes its own prebuilt version of the `ccache` utility.

[In the explanation given for why](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/refs/heads/android10-release/core/ccache.mk), they mention that "Local no-change full rebuilds were showing better results, but why not just use incremental builds at that point?"

What exactly is a "local no-change full rebuild"?

Comment: I'm not aware of that being a defined term in its own right.  Interpreting the the parts in context, I think they just mean rebuilding projects from scratch at every need, especially including when the sources have not changed since the last build for the same target platform.  This as opposed to retaining any part of previous builds.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - it sounds like your interpretation is essentially that it means a clean build.  That's kind of what it sounds like they're saying to me as well, but that would mean that using `ccache` produced *worse* times than a clean build without `ccache`, I'd find that very surprising.  If that were the case wouldn't they just say, "using `ccache` increased low long our clean builds took"?